# Custom taxonomy; link with two content types

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I've successfully created a new content type ("my_type") and added a taxonomoy into it.

How can I combine this new taxonomy also with the default content type "post", so that I can select it in the default content type backend?

Comment: Hello, msec; welcome on *Drupal Answers*. Are you using Drupal 6 or 7? The answer depends on the version you are using.

Comment: To notice that in Drupal doesn't exist a default content type, and that it is possible to assign more than one vocabulary to a content type. A complete answer is only possible if you report the Drupal version, as the setting page you need to use changes basing on the Drupal version we are talking of.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Both Drupal 6 and 7 have two content types which are created by default on a new site. They are however called page/story (D6) or page/article (D7) and not post...

Comment: @Bedir Yes, but Drupal doesn't have the concept of default content type; a default content type could be the one selected by default when you create a node, but to create a node you have to explicitly select the content type you want to create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Drupal 7

Go to Structure > Content types, select "Manage fields" for the post content type. Either add the existing taxonomy field to it or add a new one. For a new one, choose which vocabulary should be used for this field.

### Drupal 6

Go to Admin > Content > Taxonomy, edit your vocabulary. Then under content types, select the content types for which this vocabulary should be displayed.